# Go is not an internal or external command

Tags: go

I've been trying to set up my Go workspace, but it doesn't seem to be working. Whenever I type in `echo %GOPATH%`, it echoes `C:Users\y\GoWorkspace`. But whenever I type `go`, it says `go is not recognized as an internal or external command`. This is the same for any other Go command.

I am using Windows 8 64-bit with Go 1.2.2 32-bit. I have also tried Go 1.2.2 64-bit, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you added the location where you installed Go to your %PATH%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GOPATH is the path that go uses when you build or test go applications. It does not tell Windows where your go executable is. For this you have to set you path environment variable. You can also set your GOBIN environment variable.

Comment: This did not work, I added "C:\Go" to my path, and I made GOBIN "C:\Go"

Comment: It worked now, one I was missing one quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnGilmore has pointed out the GOPATH is the location the Go tools use (executables).
To set the location to the go executable so that Windows can find the command you will need to set your PATH variable.

On Windows:

```
SET %PATH%=%PATH%;C:\Go\bin
```

You can also set this so that it is in every new environment by typing 'env' into the Start->search and then choose 'Edit the system environment variables'.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was I was missing one quotation mark.